# Stopping an ongoing download without exiting Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading

I have a file that has been stuck at "2 seconds remaining" for about a day. I feel it's never going to finish, so I want to know how to cancel it without quitting or stopping Chrome.

None of these have worked:

- turning off data and WiFi.
- force "Downloads" or "Download Manager" to stop.
- clearing the data of "Downloads" or "Download Manager".
- the suggestion to force "Download Manager" to stop and *then* press "Clear Data" does not work because "Clear Data" becomes grayed out after hitting "Force stop".
- going into notification bar and pressing for some kind of cancel option.

Comment: Clearing Chrome from recent apps?

Answer (score 1):

The Download manager is just a viewing app for seeing all downloads you have done clearing it or forcing it to stop will do nothing(it will just clear the app's data and cache)
You might want to try clearing cache of chrome app since that's the app you used to download the file by going into Settings -> Apps/Installed apps ->*Locate* Chrome app -> Clear cache
If this still doesn't solve your problem you might want to clear data of the app as well (same procedure as above just click clear data) **WARNING: Clearing data will clear all bookmarks,sometimes the files that were downloaded using chrome and sign you out of chrome(which you sign in after clearing is complete) So better move all the downloaded file to other location before proceeding**
(Not a risky process i get the same problem randomly and do the same thing *most of the time clearing cache does the job*)

Answer (score 0):

Open the Downloads application, press and hold the download you would like to stop, and select the trash icon.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is no trash icon.

Comment: What rom are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Go to google search box and type Download Manager, an icon will appear below, click on it and you will see a download history, look for the file you want to cancel click and hold the file you want to cancel until you see a trash icon above , click on the trash icon and download will be cancelled.